# How can I insert an html body copied from outlook to my python code using win32 lib?

Tags: python, html, email, outlook, python-3.9

I have an email template in outlook. I could save the HTML file of it and I would like to use this HTML body in my code so I could automatize the email sending.

Is there a way to insert an exported html file here?

Or what is the format requirement to paste the html code here?

Could you please advise how could I manage this?
Thank you in advnace.

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
Email = outlook.CreateItem(0)

Email.To = emailaddress
Email.Subject = subject

Email.HTMLBody = ### I would like to insert the exported HTML body of the outlook massage here.**

attachment = 'C:\\attachment.csv'
Email.Attachments.Add(attachment)
Email.Send()
```

Comment: use `Outlook template (.oft)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Read the HTML file into a variable and use its value to set the `HTMLBody` property.